# Fragment Unit test fails with casting error

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, robolectric

Getting the below error for Horizontal pager in compose. But the app run perfectly.

```
class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class androidx.compose.ui.Modifier (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; androidx.compose.ui.Modifier is in unnamed module of loader org.robolectric.internal.AndroidSandbox$SdkSandboxClassLoader @35644fe6)
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class androidx.compose.ui.Modifier (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of
```